# Undefined variable while passing data from ajax to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, query-string

I am trying to pass amount from ajax to node js, but all I am getting is undefined in the node server. Here is the ajax code.

```
self.information = function() {
    var x = {"amount" : self.amount()};
    var string = JSON.stringify(x);
    console.log(string);
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/getIOT',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: string
      })
      .done(function(result) {
       console.log(result);
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
      })
      .always(function(data){
      });
  }
}
```

`The console.log(string) shows {"amount" : "1000"}` which looks right to me. And now in the node js server I am trying to see the variable name, but it shows undefined.

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var requestify = require('requestify');
var request = require('request');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var https = require('https');

var app = express();
app.use(helmet());

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(publicPath));


app.get('/getIOT', function (req, res , err) {
            console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
             // SHOWS {}  above
            var amount = req.body.amount;
            console.log(req.body.amount);
            // SHOWS UNDEFINED ABOVE 
});



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on ${port}`);
});
```

Using knockout js for amount, hence `self.amount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use get, just send the data as query string by changing the content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and send as json object

if you want to post:

```
 amount=12&otherprop=xxx
```

Change to

```
 var x = {"amount" : self.amount()};
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/getIOT',
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: x
  });
```

**In nodejs**

Use req.query to get the data back

```
app.get('/getIOT', function (req, res , err) {
            console.log('body: ' + req.query);
             // SHOWS {}  above
            var amount = req.query.amount;
            console.log(req.query.amount);
            // SHOWS UNDEFINED ABOVE 
});
```

Comment: Your answer helped me perfectly, but I want to ask, the POST did not work for me, can you tell me why it caused me an error?

Comment: I Get a error. SyntaxError: Unexpected token a at parse (/Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/body-p‌​arser/lib/types/json‌​.js:83:15) at /Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/body-pa‌​rser/lib/read.js:116‌​:18 at invokeCallback (/Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/raw-bo‌​dy/index.js:262:16) at done (/Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/raw-bo‌​dy/index.js:251:7)

Comment: Oh.. Just parse the json string instead of stringify. Change JSON.stringify(req.body) to JSON.parse(req.body);

Comment: You're sending json string to nodejs, why you have to stringify that again. Just parse that json string if you want to use post.

Comment: Also remove bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}). This tell the browser to send url form encoded data rather than json.

Comment: If you still have problem, just open another question related to the post so that anyone can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that jQuery's `.ajax` sends the data in query parameters if you use an HTTP GET request.  I'd check `req.query` rather than `req.body`, or change the ajax call be `type: 'POST'` to get it in `req.body`.

If that just sounds like a bunch of nonsense, I can try to explain in more detail :)

Comment: Since OP set the `contentType` to `contentType: 'application/json'` in the Request, it should be received in `req.body`

Comment: Are you sure?  From the jQuery docs for the data attribute:

`Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).`

Comment: @thataustin POST gives bad request :(

Comment: I think with a `POST` request, you don't need to stringify it.  Just pass in an JS object:   `data: x`.

Also, remember to tell the server that you're expecting a post by changin `app.get` to `app.post`.

But to be honest, I think using the query params is better.  Did `req.query` work?

Comment: @thataustin, You are on the right track (and I wasn't).  GET requests do not populate `req.body` but POST requests do.

Comment: @thataustin I Get a error. 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a
    at parse (/Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
    at done (/Users/nihit/Documents/node/multiple-js/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)

Comment: @MasnadNihit, if it's a bad request, then fix it.  You need a POST request.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I am getting that error, shown above, I am not sure why.

Comment: Are you still sending `string` ?  Or are you sending `x`?  And are you sending it via `post` or `get`?  We need a reset here :)

Comment: @MasnadNihit, read the docs on sending a POST request in jQuery.  You'll have your answer.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I read it, and I know for a fact I am sending a js object, but I am not sure why its still giving a bad request

Comment: @MasnadNihit It's because you are not sending proper JSON.  `Unexpected token a at parse...`.  `console.log` your payload before sending the request and you'll see.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah so should I make it stringify?

Comment: @MasnadNihit no

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah sorry I meant Parse it.